# iTunes Smart Playlist combining 2 genres

Tags: itunes, playlists, smart-playlist

Let say for example that I want an iTunes playlist that includes **All Hip-Hop and Rap songs**.

I create a smart play list with:

```
Genre > contains > Hip-Hop
Genre > contains > Rap
```

But then I only have the songs that are in **both** Rap and Hip-Hop.
Is there a way I can make a playlist of all songs that contain at least one of the two genres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In each Smart Playlist, you can change "Match **ALL** of the following rules" to "Match **ANY**"" to tell iTunes to do a OR instead of AND between elements you specify:

```
Match ANY of the following:
Genre > contains > Hip-Hop  
OR  
Genre > contains > Rap
```

Unfortunately you can't mix OR and ANDs in the same playlist, it's all or nothing. For example you cannot do the following since any song rated 4 or more -no matter the genre!- will be included:

```
Match ANY of the following:
Rating > greater than or equal > 4 stars
OR
Genre > contains > Hip-Hop  
OR  
Genre > contains > Rap
```

### Multiple Smart Playlists

To solve this problem, you can create and combine multiple smart playlists that focus on one thing. For example:

**Smart Playlist 1: 4+ stars ratings**

```
Match ALL or ANY of the following:
Rating > greater than or equal > 4 stars
```

**Smart Playlist 2: Hip-hop & Rap**

```
Match ANY of the following:
Genre > contains > Hip-Hop  
OR  
Genre > contains > Rap
```

**Smart Playlist 3: 4+ rated Hip-hop & Rap** (if you want to sync to your device, just sync this one)

```
Match ALL of the following:
Playlist > is > Hip-hop & Rap
AND 
Playlist > is > 4+ stars ratings
```

Comment: great! that's really silly you can't mix conditionals though

Answer (score -1):

Quick fix for Single songs will be to make a playlist:

Love

Then exclude all unwanted Genre.

Comment: So make a playlist, make love, exclude genre?  Must it be in that sequence?